# Convergence of Integral near 0

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I am trying to determine the convergence of the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 \frac{f(x)}{x}\, dx
\end{equation}
given that $f(x)$ is bounded and continuous on $[0,1]$, and that $f(x)=0$.  The boundedness is just so that the question of convergence is only at the point $x=0$.  I specifically want $f$ to be only continuous on $[0,1]$ and not differentiable in a neighborhood of the origin as I could just use a Taylor expansion of $f$ to solve the problem then.

I believe that the integral should converge but I can't figure out exactly how to write it down.  Since $1/x$ is the critical exponent of convergence near $0$ it seems that multiplying $1/x$ by any function which vanishes at the origin should be enough to make the integral converge.  More concretely, if $f(x)=x^{1/n} log(x)^m$ then $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=0$ for all positive values of $n$ and $m$, and $\int_0^1 f(x)/x \, dx < \infty$.  The derivative of these $f$ become infinite as $x\to 0$, and at faster rates for larger $m$ and $n$, so they are good candidates for $\int f(x)/x$ to not converge, yet the integral still converges.

Any suggestions for a proof, or a counterexample to show the integral does not always converge would be much appreciated.

Comment: One nice approach is to use the [Weierstrass approximation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_approximation_theorem) to show that there is a sequence of polynomials $f_n(x)$ such that $f_n \to f$ uniformly and $f_n(0) = 0$.  From there, it follows that $f_n(x)/x \to f(x)/x$ uniformly, so that the limit of the integrals is the integral of the limit.

Comment: Try $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+|\log x|}$ for $x>0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: That counter example works Kelenner, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counterexample was given in comments by [Kelenner](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915112/convergence-of-integral-near-0#comment1888920_915112): $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+|\log x|}$ for $x>0$ and $f(0)=0$.

You may be interested in the concept of [Dini continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini_continuity). If a function is Dini-continuous, and $f(0)=0$, then $\int_0^1 \frac{f(x)}{x} \,dx$ converges.

Dini continuity can be awkward to work with, but it's the weakest assumption that makes the logarithmic divergence in $1/x$ go away. As a result, it comes up in the context of singular integral operators.

The better known assumption of *Hölder continuity*   implies Dini continuity, and thus is sufficient for your purpose. Both of these are much weaker than differentiability.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I think Holder continuity is precisely the distinction I was looking for.