# Given a coin that produces the probability $\lambda$, what is a constructive way to produce $f(\lambda)$, where $f$ is continuous non-Hölder?

Tags: probability, polynomials, approximation-theory, simulation, holder-spaces

Given a coin of "bias" $\lambda$, sample the probability $f(\lambda)$. This is the *Bernoulli factory problem*, and it can be solved only for certain functions $f$. (For example, flipping the coin twice and taking heads only if exactly one coin shows heads, we can simulate the probability $\lambda(1-\lambda)$.)

Usually, the Bernoulli factory problem can be solved for $f$ if and only if—

- $f$ is continuous in $[0, 1]$, and
- $f$ is identically $0$, identically $1$, or polynomially bounded away from $0$ and $1$ (roughly speaking, the function takes on only values in $ [0, 1]$ and its graph doesn't touch $0$ or $1$ except at the points $0$ and/or $1$)

(Keane and O'Brien 1994).

This question is a continuation of [another question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3904732/what-are-ways-to-compute-polynomials-that-converge-from-above-and-below-to-a-con), but this time we focus on the case when $f(\lambda)$ is a **continuous non-Hölder function**, which roughly means a continuous function with an exponentially steep slope (steeper than any $n$th-root).

The question just linked to seeks ways to compute polynomials that converge from above and below to $f$ in a manner that solves the Bernoulli factory problem for $f$. These polynomials form an *approximation scheme* for $f$. See that question for a formal statement of such approximation schemes.

There are [two algorithms](https://peteroupc.github.io/bernoulli.html#General_Factory_Functions) (one by Thomas and Blanchet $2012$, another by Łatuszyński et al.) to simulate a function $f$ via an approximation scheme. Roughly speaking, the algorithms work as follows:

1. Generate U, a uniform random number in $[0, 1]$.
2. Flip the input coin (with "bias" $\lambda$), then build an upper and lower bound for $f(\lambda)$, based on the outcomes of the flips so far. In this case, these bounds come from two degree-$n$ polynomials that approach $f$ as $n$ gets large, where $n$ is the number of coin flips so far in the algorithm.
3. If U is less than or equal to the lower bound, return 1. If U is greater than the upper bound, return $0$. Otherwise, go to step $2$.

The result of the algorithm is $1$ with probability *exactly* equal to $f(\lambda)$, or $0$ otherwise.

In general, the rate at which a function can be simulated by these algorithms depends on the smoothness of $f$. It roughly corresponds to the rate of convergence of an approximation scheme for $f$. I list [approximation schemes](https://peteroupc.github.io/bernsupp.html#Approximation_Schemes) for different kinds of functions $f$, which work with the two algorithms described above.

For example, roughly speaking, a $C^0$ continuous function $f$ can be simulated at the rate $O(n^{\alpha})$ only if $f$ is $\alpha$-Hölder continuous (Holtz et al. 2011). This seems to imply that a function not meeting a *Hölder condition* (a non-Hölder function) can achieve, at best, a simulation rate of $O(1)$, so that the polynomials won't necessarily converge uniformly for all $\lambda \in [0, 1]$ and for all non-Hölder functions, so that the algorithms above won't terminate in all cases.

<s>And this suggests to me that we need to add the following extra condition to the Bernoulli factory problem, since it appears that no approximation scheme exists for non-Hölder functions:</s>

- $f$ is $\alpha$-Hölder continuous in its domain for some $\alpha > 0$.

Is this true? Is there really no algorithm to sample the probability $f(\lambda)$ for a non-Hölder function $f$, given sample access to the probability $\lambda$?

*This suggests that a different approach may be needed for Hölder functions. Thus: Is there a constructive method to approximate non-Hölder functions with polynomials for the Bernoulli factory problem (in the form of a formula to compute their coefficients), so that we can sample the probability $f(\lambda)$ for a non-Hölder function $f$, given sample access to the probability $\lambda$?*

**Note:** An example of a non-Hölder function is the following, with a "cusp" at $0$:

- $1/10$ if $\lambda = 0$, and
- $-1/(2*\ln(\lambda/2))+1/10$ otherwise.

Another example is the following, where the cusp is at $3/10$:

- $1/10$ if $\lambda = 3/10$, and
- $-1/(2*\ln(\frac{|\lambda-3/10|}{2}))+1/10$ otherwise.

A third example is the following monotone function:

- $3/10$ if $\lambda = 3/10$,
- $1/(2*\ln(\frac{3/10-\lambda}{2}))+3/10$ if $\lambda < 3/10$, and
- $-1/(2*\ln(\frac{\lambda-3/10}{2}))+3/10$ otherwise.

Roughly speaking:

- A non-Hölder function is continuous but has an exponentially steep slope.
- If a continuous function has no vertical slope, the function is 1-Hölder continuous.

REFERENCES:

- Thomas, A.C., Blanchet, J., "[A Practical Implementation of the Bernoulli Factory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.2508v3)", arXiv:1106.2508v3 [stat.AP], 2012.
- Łatuszyński, K., Kosmidis, I., Papaspiliopoulos, O., Roberts, G.O., "Simulating events of unknown probabilities via reverse time martingales", arXiv:0907.4018v2 [stat.CO], $2009/2011$.
- Keane, M. S., and O'Brien, G. L., "A Bernoulli factory", ACM Transactions on Modeling and Computer Simulation 4(2), 1994.
- Holtz, O., Nazarov, F., Peres, Y., "[New Coins from Old, Smoothly](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00365-010-9108-5.pdf)", Constructive Approximation $33$ ($2011$).

---

**Update:**

I have become aware of so-called *Dini-continuous functions*, which are a superset of Hölder continuous functions.

Essentially, a Dini-continuous function has a slope no "steeper" than that of $\phi(\lambda)$ for some increasing non-negative function $\phi$ with a finite integral of $\phi(\lambda)/\lambda$ over $[0, 1]$.

However, I haven't found any paper yet on the rate at which polynomials can approximate a Dini-continuous (but not Hölder-continuous) function (let alone in a manner that solves the Bernoulli factory problem).

Moreover, the following function, adapted from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915112/convergence-of-integral-near-0), is apparently not even Dini continuous:

- $1/10 + (1/(1+|\ln(\lambda)|))/2$ if $\lambda>0$, and
- $1/10$ otherwise.

Comment: The problem formulation and structural requirements could be described more.

Comment: @Michael: Edited.

Comment: Keane and O'Brian give a necessary and sufficient condition for simulation: The function $f$  should be continuous in $[0,1]$ and both $f$ and $1-f$ should not vanish faster than polynomially at the endpoints. In light of that, I do not understand the question.

Comment: @YuvalPeres: Yes, when I asked this question, I doubted whether algorithms that could simulate non-Hölder continuous functions could exist because, at the time, I wasn't aware of any method that could approximate a function not meeting a Hölder condition with polynomials in a manner that solves the Bernoulli factory problem.  For example, your paper with Holtz and Nazarov covers only Hölder continuous functions bounded away from 0 and 1.  Since then I found the result in my answer, which greatly addresses the matter.

Comment: @YuvalPeres: Also, I am aware of Theorem 26 of Nacu and Peres 2005, but it's not expressed as a formula that allows calculating the approximating polynomials' coefficients for an arbitrary degree, in a manner similar to [another answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3945261/721857) or this question's answer.

Comment: Doesn't the original proof of Keane and O'Brien also work here?

Comment: @YuvalPeres: [Previous comment rewritten:] The approach in that proof is interesting, but it seems that, just like Theorem 26 and rather than giving a formula that computes the approximating polynomials for a whole class of functions, the method requires computing the necessary degree of approximation (finding $k_a$ for each polynomial $a$, or for Theorem 26, finding $s_i$ for each polynomial $i$), and this has to be done for _each_ function $f$ to be simulated.  [1/2]

Comment: @YuvalPeres: [cont'd:] And this makes the proof impractical to use, esp. since for a given $f$, it's not guaranteed whether the $k_a$'s will show a pattern or keep that pattern "forever". [2/2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked on this and found the following result, which shows that any continuous function meeting the two conditions in my question admits an approximation scheme with polynomials (in a manner that solves the Bernoulli factory problem). This includes continuous functions that are not Hölder continuous. The method of proving the result goes back to Nacu and Peres (2005).

**Result:** *Let $f(\lambda)$ be a continuous function that maps [0, 1] to [0, 1], and let $X$ be a hypergeometric($2n$, $k$, $n$) random variable. Let $\omega(x)$ be a modulus of continuity of $f$ (a non-negative and nondecreasing function in the interval [0, 1], for which $|f(x)-f(y)|\le\omega(|x-y|)$ for all $x$ in [0, 1] and all $y$ in [0, 1]). If $\omega$ is concave on [0, 1], then the expression—$$|\mathbb{E}[f(X/n)]-f(k/(2n))|, $$is bounded from above by—*

- $\omega(\sqrt{\frac{1}{8n-4}})$, _for all n≥1 that are integer powers of 2, _
- $\omega(\sqrt{\frac{1}{7n}})$, *for all n≥4 that are integer powers of 2, and*
- $\omega(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}})$, *for all n≥1 that are integer powers of 2.*

**Proof:** *ω* is assumed to be non-negative because absolute values are non-negative. To prove the first and second bounds: abs(**E**[*f*(*X*/*n*)] − *f*(*k*/(2 * *n*))) ≤ **E**[abs(*f*(*X*/*n*) − *f*(*k*/(2 * *n*))] ≤ **E**[*ω*(abs(*X*/*n* − *k*/(2 * *n*))] ≤ *ω*(**E**[abs(*X*/*n* − *k*/(2 * *n*))]) (by Jensen's inequality and because *ω* is concave) ≤ *ω*(sqrt(**E**[abs(*X*/*n* − *k*/(2 * *n*))]<sup>2</sup>)) = *ω*(sqrt(**Var**[*X*/*n*])) = *ω*(sqrt((*k**(2 * *n* − *k*)/(4*(2 * *n* −1)**n*<sup>2</sup>)))) ≤ *ω*(sqrt((*n*<sup>2</sup>/(4*(2 * *n* −1)**n*<sup>2</sup>)))) = *ω*(sqrt((1/(8**n* −4)))) = *ρ*, and for all *n* ≥4 that are integer powers of 2, *ρ* ≤ *ω*(sqrt(1/(7**n*))). To prove the third bound: abs(**E**[*f*(*X*/*n*)] − *f*(*k*/(2 * *n*))) ≤ *ω*(sqrt(**Var**[*X*/*n*])) ≤ *ω*(sqrt(1/(2*n))). □

The only technical barrier, though, is to solve the functional equation—$$\delta(n) = \delta(2n) + \kappa(n), $$ where $\kappa(n)$ is one of the bounds proved above, such as $\omega\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{8n-4}}\right)$.

In general, the solution to this equation is—$$\delta(2^m) = \sum_{k=m}^\infty \kappa(2^k), $$ where $n = 2^m$ and $m\ge0$ are integers, provided the sum converges.

In this case, the third bound has a trivial solution when $\omega(x)$ is of the form $cx^\alpha$, but not in general.

Now, we approximate $f$ with polynomials in Bernstein form of power-of-two degrees. These are two sequences of polynomials that converge to $f$ from above and below, such that their coefficients "increase" and "decrease" just as the polynomials themselves do. In general, for all $n\ge1$ that are integer powers of 2:

- The $k$th Bernstein coefficient for the upper polynomial of $n$th degree is $f(k/n) + \delta(n)$.
- The $k$th Bernstein coefficient for the lower polynomial of $n$th degree is $f(k/n) - \delta(n)$.

Thus, for the polynomials of degree $n$, $\delta(n)$ is the amount by which to shift the approximating polynomials upward and downward.

---

**Remark:**

Theorem 26 of Nacu and Peres (2005) and the proof of Keane and O'Brien (1994) give general ways to simulate continuous factory functions $f(\lambda)$ on the interval $[0, 1]$.  The former is limited to functions that are bounded away from 0 and 1, while the latter is not.  However, both methods don't provide formulas of the form $f(k/n) \pm \delta(n)$ that work for a whole class of factory functions (such as formulas of the kind given earlier in this answer).  For this and other reasons, given below, both methods are impractical:

- Before a given function $f$ can be simulated, the methods require computing the necessary degree of approximation (finding $k_a$ or $s_i$ for each polynomial $a$ or $i$, respectively).  This work has to be repeated for *each* function $f$ to be simulated.
- Computing the degree of approximation involves, among other things, checking whether the approximating polynomial is "close enough" to $f$, which can require a symbolic maximization.
- This computation gets more and more time-intensive with increasing degree.
- For a given $f$, it's not guaranteed whether the $k_a$'s (or $s_i$'s) will show a pattern or keep that pattern "forever" — especially since only a finite number of approximation degrees can be computed with these methods.

REFERENCES:

- Nacu, Şerban, and Yuval Peres. "[**Fast simulation of new coins from old**](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoap/1106922322)", The Annals of Applied Probability 15, no. 1A (2005): 93-115.